# how to fix ' find the prime factors of a number' in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to find the prime factor for a number by the following code:

```
def pf(n):
    f=[]
    while n != 1:
        for i in range(2, n+1):
            if n%i == 0:
                f.append(i)
                n //=i
    return f
```

The output for pf(8) is [2, 4], rather than [2,2,2] as my expect.
The output for pf(16) is [2,4,2], rather than [2,2,2,2].
can anyone help me to figure out what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

If you break inside the loop, you will get what you want :

```
def pf(n):
    f=[]
    while n != 1:
        for i in range(2, n+1):
            if n%i == 0:
                f.append(i)
                n //=i
                break
    return f
```

#### Why was it wrong ?

in you first for loop, `8` is can be divied by `2`, so n is equal to `4`. And when i is then equals to `4`, then 4 is added as a prime factor

#### Other implementation:

I prefer this implementation :)

```
def pf(n):
    f=[]
    i = 2
    while n != 1:
        if n%i == 0:
            f.append(i)
            n //=i
        else:
            i += 1
    return f
```

This implementation avoids you to recompute the numbers in range you already know is not dividable by.